# How to prove this equality with rotation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vectors, rotations

The question is

> Show that the length of a free vector is not changed by rotation, that
> is, that $\lVert v \rVert = \lVert Rv \rVert$

My attempt is let $R=\begin{bmatrix} c_\theta & -s_\theta \\ s_\theta & c_\theta \end{bmatrix}$ and $v=[v_x \ v_y]^T$ where $c_\theta = \cos\theta,s_\theta=\sin\theta$.
$$
\begin{align}
\lVert Rv \rVert &= \lVert
\begin{bmatrix} c_\theta & -s_\theta \\ s_\theta & c_\theta \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} v_x \\ v_y \end{bmatrix}
\rVert = \lVert
\begin{bmatrix} v_xc_\theta - v_ys_\theta \\ v_xs_\theta + v_yc_\theta \end{bmatrix} \rVert \\
&= \sqrt{ (v_xc_\theta - v_ys_\theta )^2 + (v_xs_\theta + v_yc_\theta)^2} \\
&= \sqrt{ v^2_xc^2_\theta + v^2_ys^2_\theta + 2v_xv_yc_\theta s_\theta + v^2_xs^2_\theta + v^2_yc^2_\theta - 2v_xv_yc_\theta s_\theta} \\
&= \sqrt{v^2_x(c^2_\theta+s^2_\theta) + v^2_y(c^2_\theta+s^2_\theta) } \\
&= \sqrt{v^2_x + v^2_y } \\
&= \lVert v \rVert
\end{align}
$$
Obviously this works for 2D but I can't guarantee my proof to work in higher dimensions. Any suggestions for alternatives to prove this? Also, is my proof valid for higher dimensions?

Comment: **Hint:** A rotation is an isometry.

Comment: In higher dimensions, what is your definition of "rotation"?

Comment: @5xum for 3D, it is not unique. We have several representations.

Comment: @Surb I need to read about the isometry. Thanks though.

Comment: @CroCo So how can you answer questions about rotations if you don't have a definition of them?

Comment: @5xum I know they are  orthogonal and their determinant is 1. Also, each column is a unit vector. So they share same properties.

Comment: A rotation in 3D can be thought of as sequence of rotations each in 2D.  i.e. rotate $\theta$ units in the xy plane (around the z axis) and $\phi$ units in the $yz$ plane (around the x axis).  Each of these rotations leaves distances invariant.  Another way to think about this is "what does this transformation do to each of my basis vectors."  If lengths are unchanged for each basis vector, then it will be unchanged for all combinations of these basis vectors.

Comment: @DougM " If lengths are unchanged for each basis vector, then it will be unchanged for all combinations of these basis vectors." Well, you need an orthogonal basis for the norm to be additive for linear combinations of the basis.

Comment: @surb You are right, I wasn't quite thinking it through when I wrote that comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you seem to know that any rotation is orthogonal, it is pretty easy: An orthogonal matrix satisfies $R^TR=I$ or equivalently $R^T = R^{-1}$ which is either your definition of an orthogonal matrix or a consequence of your definition (it might be the case that you defined orthogonal matrices in a different way).

Then we can calculate
$$||v||^2 = \langle v, v \rangle = \langle v, R^TRv \rangle = \langle Rv, Rv \rangle = ||Rv||^2$$
and by taking the square root we have what we wanted to show.